# How to increase parameter length in WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get my WEB API to accept long request strings, but no matter what I try, I end up getting a 400 Bad Request. My method is accessed via:

> http://server/api/controller/method/{input}

The code is

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult method(string input) {
   //Do Stuff
   return Ok();
}
```

The following type of call will work just fine.

> http://server/api/controller/ShortInputString

However something like:

> http://server/api/controller/SuperHugeReallyReallyLongInputString

results in a 400 Bad Request.

From my understanding, this is because the there is a max length that my input argument can have. I have tried increasing this in the following ways found in other Stack Overflow posts, yet none of them work.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="4096"/> //in web.config

    <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
    <!--50MB-->
  </requestFiltering>
</security> //also in web.config 


config.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter.ReadBufferSize = int.MaxValue / 10; //in WebApiConfig.cs
```

None of the above seem to have any impact on the max length the input can be. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is not max allowed content length. It is the URL length. Which maxes out at around 2,000 characters. You may need to POST your input in the body of the request.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to build a quick Proof of Concept for something and was hoping I could do this instead of fighting with CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up stumbling across something that worked.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amyd/2014/02/06/response-400-bad-request-on-long-url/

Need to add or update the following registry key:

> HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\UrlSegmentMaxLength

Also still need to do:

```
<httpRuntimetargetFramework="4.5" maxUrlLength="2083" maxQueryStringLength="2048" />
```

Lastly restart the http service. Just like the author, I could not get this to work, so I simply rebooted.